# can two variables operated equate to a constant in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, operators

I need to have two variables, x and y, and an equation involving both that always equals one. 
This is a simple example. This example may be easy to define in terms of y, like y = 1/x, but I have another equation I need to use, and it is too hard to define in terms of y.

```
var x, y;
x*y = 1;
x = Math.random()*20;
console.log(y);
```

I would get an error message for this, like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (line 2)
```

a variable could be defined as `x*y`, like `var z= x*y`, but apparently not a constant. Maybe there is some way around this, like defining two variables, one as the constant and the other as the equation and finding some way to relate them? Maybe javascript's looseness will allow for some new technique?

Thanks ahead of time! :)

Comment: Programming languages do not work like that.

Comment: `=` means *assignment*, not a mathematical equality.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly. The value of `x` depends on the value of `y`. You must describe their dependency.

You can do something like:

```
var x_y = (function () {
    var x = 1, y = 1;
    return {
        set_x: function (new_x) {
            x = new_x;
            y = 1 / new_x;
        },
        set_y: function (new_y) {
            y = new_y;
            x = 1 / new_y;
        },
        get_x: function () {
            return x;
        },
        get_y: function () {
            return y;
        }
    };
}());
x_y.set_x(Math.random()*20);
console.log(x_y.get_y());
```

So essentially we're saying `x = 1 / y;` and `y = 1 / x;` and we couple the values: if you change one, the other changes as well.

Comment: this would work great when it is easy to define y in terms of x, but I need to use an equation that is too hard to define in terms of y. But thanks for offering your answer.

Comment: I don't see a way around that. If you want to know `y` for a given `x` you have to know the operation. The alternative would be to use some a heuristic that tries to _guess_ the value of `y`.